# Owl Carousel css set to display:none when page has loaded

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm having an issue with my Owl Carousel on my page. Currently, the carousel container and items don't display. Iused my web inspector to check the element and it appears that it has the line `display:none` in the css. However, when I change this to `display:block`, the items show one under the other, rather than in a line horizontally.

My script for the carousel is as follows:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        dots:true,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        items:4,
        responsive:{
          0:{
            items:1
          },
            480:{
        items:2
          },
            768 :{
        items:4  
          }
        }
    })
});
```

My HTML markup is as follows:

```
<div class="row owl-carousel container">
    <div id="layers-widget-carousel-5-931" class="item layers-widget-carousel-931">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="layers-widget-carousel-5-715" class="item layers-widget-carousel-715">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="layers-widget-carousel-5-95" class="item layers-widget-carousel-95">
    ...
    </div>
```

I have the scripts owl.carousel.min.js, owl.carousel.css and owl.theme.default.css loaded in the head (didn't work when loaded in the footer either).

Is there any obvious reason why this might not be working?

Comment: Any console errors showing up, conflicts, etc? I use Owl Carousel a lot and nearly always run into an issue at some point or another...

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? There might be a global css property for the element, but perhaps the script is set to only display one item at a time (is the style attribute being changed in the DOM).

Comment: @samuidavid yes you're right actually, I get an error referring to fancybox script - just removed it and it works - thanks for the hand!!

Comment: Nice, perhaps there was a jQuery conflict that prevented Owl from running?

Answer (score 7):

I was having this issue and it was because I forgot to add the js call at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

Comment: To be more specific, place the call after calling the owl.carousel.min.js file somewhere in the footer

Answer (score 3):

With version 1.3.3 I had the same problem. I didn't see the carousel, because items had "display:none" in CSS. When I changed "display:none" into "display:block" I could see the items, but as a column.

I discovered, that the link to owl.carousel.js was in a wrong place, in the header. I moved it to the footer, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

!!!Attention!!!

If u have this problem all u should do to solve it is to replace owl library before your scripts.
Example:

```
<footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- here goes your scripts -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was in the same spot as you.
I searched and searched and ended up here.

Just out of curiosity I updated the JS and CSS to the latest version. So that worked for me.

However, I also found this - [Link to Github item](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/368)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same "non working" issue and solved it by abandoning version 2.2 of the carousel and reverting back to version 1.3. This isn't a good solution though, the current version should be fixed. I don't want to be mucking around with a plug-in just to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

only added for container display:none  and carusel added display:block himself

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling owlCarousel() in a function, make sure the document is ready first. Example .js file:

```js
(function ($) {
  function initOwlCarousel() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    initOwlCarousel();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the scripts in the head tag instead of putting them at the end of body tag!

Answer (score -1):

Guys i found the solution. Your jquery file needs to be above your owl javascript file. That easy.

Just make sure your jquery is above everything cause it needs to be executed first.

Comment: When you say you found the solution, can you explain how you know that that is the solution?

Comment: This seems to already be covered by other answers here

Comment: i made a video about it > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or4pKNrk37s